printf() prints only the first character
Recently I came across an example from the book "The C Programming Language" and decided to run it:
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main() {

    int c, nl, nw, nc, state; 

    state = OUT; 
    nl = nw = nc = 0; 
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc; 
        if (c == '\n') 
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') 
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN; 
            ++nw;
        } 
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}

There is a problem related to printf(). For some reason, only the first character is printed, although there should be 3 of them. What could be the problem?
System - Windows. For editing code I use Visual Studio Code. Compiler - gcc.
Interesting fact: on macOS this problem do not occur and the output is as needed.
Input:
a       
ab 
abc
abcd

Output:
4

Desired output:
4 4 14

Thanks in advance!
ANSWER:
I used control-C thinking that it was suitable as an EOF-indicator. The correct option is to use control-Z.

I do not reproduce the result presented in the question, and I do not expect to do. If you are running the program inside VSC then that may be causing the issue.  Or maybe you just need to scroll the output window?

@JohnBollinger I tried to write this code in notepad and compile it by calling gcc in cmd, but the problem was not solved.

The wind shifted the code, but the simpler version outputs 4 5 21 with MSVC (or 5 5 22 if there was a final newline) .Please copy paste the exact code, input and output, and desired output. Don't mess with it.

Aside if you are using Notepad to write source code, then you should immediately upgrade to Notepad++.

I just ran that (in Windows) and got the correct output.

Re the next edit: MSVC ouputs 4 4 22 because of the trailing spaces in the input text.

@WeatherVane this is more of a response to John Bollinger than a real use case. Аt the very least this shows that the issue is not directly related to VSC.

@OldBoy nice to you

And I just ran it under Ubuntu using gcc and got the same result. So whatever it is that you are doing, you are not telling us the whole story. Please capture ALL the output from the  point you start the gcc compiler to the point that your program completes.

VSC if a very powerful text editor, that supports a number of plugins and is highly configurable. Because of that, it is easy to produce a wrong configuration that can cause almost anything to happen. Please show the exact commands that you use to build and run the program in a cmd line with the exact output... This kind of error is often caused by building a new version of the program and still executing an obsolete one.

@L1M8054N Better to post your answer below than in the question

The idea here is:

to count letters, words and lines from the input file. Words are separated by spaces or tabs or newlines.
the program implements a minimalist FSM, a finite state machine with 2 states.

I am not sure I understand the question, but here is the output for this file
one another
one
another

3 4 24

And it seems ok. Note that is you are testing this interactively control-Z is the EOF indicator.
